# Promises with Node.js and Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a function, which have a structure struct in parameters, and this struct is setted by some asynchronous SQL request, as in the code below :

```
module.exports.loadDatas = function(struct) {

    db.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.vector;')
    .then(function(records){
        for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
        {
          if(records[i].type=="ADSL")   
          {
            struct.labelAdsl=records[i].type;
          }
          else if (records[i].type=="Cable")
          {
            struct.labelCable=records[i].type;
          }
          else if (records[i].type=="Fibre")
          {
            struct.labelFibre=records[i].type;
          }
          else if (records[i].type=="Others")
          {
            struct.labelOthers=records[i].type;
          }
          else if (records[i].type=="Ott")
          {
            struct.labelOtt=records[i].type;
          }
          else if (records[i].type=="Satellite")
          {
            struct.labelSatellite=records[i].type;
          }
          else if (records[i].type=="Tnt")
          {
            struct.labelTnt=records[i].type;
          }
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      throw err;
    });

  db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.data;")
    .then(function (records){
      for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
      {
        let record= records[i];

        if(record.vector_id==0)
        {
          factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastAdsl, struct.valueReturnAdsl, record);       
        }

        else if(record.vector_id==1)
        {
          factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastCable, struct.valueReturnCable, record);        
        }

        else if(record.vector_id==2)
        {
          factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastFibre, struct.valueReturnFibre, record);
        }

        else if(record.vector_id==3)
        {
          factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastOthers, struct.valueReturnOthers, record);
        }

        else if(record.vector_id==4)
        {
          factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastOtt, struct.valueReturnOtt, record);
        }

        else if(record.vector_id==5)
        {
          factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastSatellite, struct.valueReturnSatellite, record);
        }

        else if(record.vector_id==6)
        {
          factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastTnt, struct.valueReturnTnt, record);
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      throw err;
    });

  db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.admin;")
    .then(function (records){
      for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
      {
        struct.adminList[i]=records[i].name;
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      throw err;
    });

  db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.media;")
    .then(function (records){
      for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
      {
        struct.mediaList[i] = { label : records[i].label, value : records[i].value};
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      throw err;
    });

  db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.scroll ORDER BY orderscroll;")
    .then(function (records){
      for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
      {
        let record= records[i];

        if(record.isscrolled==false)
        {
          if(record.idm==null && record.vector_id !=null)
          {
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].platform = struct.listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
            struct.indj++;
          }
          else if(record.vector_id==null && record.idm!=null)
          {
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].media = struct.listMedias[record.idm-1];
            struct.indj++;
          }
          else
          {
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].media = struct.listMedias[record.idm-1];
            struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].platform = struct.listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
            struct.indj++;  
          }    
        }

        else if(record.isscrolled==true)
        {
          if(record.idm==null && record.vector_id !=null)
          {
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk].platform = struct.listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
            struct.indk++;
          }
          else if(record.vector_id==null && record.idm!=null)
          {
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk].media = struct.listMedias[record.idm-1];
            struct.indk++;
          }
          else
          {
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk].media = struct.listMedias[record.idm-1];
            struct.listScroll[struct.indk].platform = struct.listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
            struct.indk++;  
          }       
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      throw err;
    });

  db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.device;")
    .then(function (records){
      for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
      {
        struct.deviceList[i] = {value : records[i].value,  label : records[i].label};
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      throw err;
    });

  db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.listmsd;")
    .then(function (records){
      for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
      {
        let aaa = records[i].namelist;
        let ccc = [];
        struct.msdList[i] = {id: records[i].idlistmsd, labelList: aaa, msds : []};  
      }

      let k = struct.msdList.length;

      db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.msd;")
        .then(function (records1)
        {
          for(j=0; j<records1.length; j++)
          {
            for(l=0;l<k;l++)
            {
              if(records1[j].listmsd==struct.msdList[l].id)
              {
                struct.msdList[l].msds.push(records1[j].msd);
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          throw err;
        });         
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      throw err;
    });


}
```

However, I want to make a super promise (for this I use bluebird.js) like this (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/new-promise.html) in order to return the struct setted, after all the MySQL request are executed.

But with the parameter passed, how to organize it ?

I try with Promise.all but it does'nt work.

```
var pr1 = db.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.vector;')
      .then(function(records){
          for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
          {
            if(records[i].type=="ADSL")   
            {
              struct.labelAdsl=records[i].type;
            }
            else if (records[i].type=="Cable")
            {
              struct.labelCable=records[i].type;
            }
            else if (records[i].type=="Fibre")
            {
              struct.labelFibre=records[i].type;
            }
            else if (records[i].type=="Others")
            {
              struct.labelOthers=records[i].type;
            }
            else if (records[i].type=="Ott")
            {
              struct.labelOtt=records[i].type;
            }
            else if (records[i].type=="Satellite")
            {
              struct.labelSatellite=records[i].type;
            }
            else if (records[i].type=="Tnt")
            {
              struct.labelTnt=records[i].type;
            }
          }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        throw err;
      });

    var pr2 = db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.data;")
      .then(function (records){
        for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
        {
          let record= records[i];

          if(record.vector_id==0)
          {
            factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastAdsl, struct.valueReturnAdsl, record);       
          }

          else if(record.vector_id==1)
          {
            factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastCable, struct.valueReturnCable, record);        
          }

          else if(record.vector_id==2)
          {
            factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastFibre, struct.valueReturnFibre, record);
          }

          else if(record.vector_id==3)
          {
            factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastOthers, struct.valueReturnOthers, record);
          }

          else if(record.vector_id==4)
          {
            factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastOtt, struct.valueReturnOtt, record);
          }

          else if(record.vector_id==5)
          {
            factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastSatellite, struct.valueReturnSatellite, record);
          }

          else if(record.vector_id==6)
          {
            factorizeSQL(UTCGap, struct.cllForecastTnt, struct.valueReturnTnt, record);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        throw err;
      });

    var pr3 = db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.admin;")
      .then(function (records){
        for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
        {
          struct.adminList[i]=records[i].name;
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        throw err;
      });

    var pr4 = db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.media;")
      .then(function (records){
        for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
        {
          struct.mediaList[i] = { label : records[i].label, value : records[i].value};
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        throw err;
      });

    var pr5 = db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.scroll ORDER BY orderscroll;")
      .then(function (records){
        for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
        {
          let record= records[i];

          if(record.isscrolled==false)
          {
            if(record.idm==null && record.vector_id !=null)
            {
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].platform = struct.listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
              struct.indj++;
            }
            else if(record.vector_id==null && record.idm!=null)
            {
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].media = struct.listMedias[record.idm-1];
              struct.indj++;
            }
            else
            {
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].media = struct.listMedias[record.idm-1];
              struct.listUnScroll[struct.indj].platform = struct.listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
              struct.indj++;  
            }    
          }

          else if(record.isscrolled==true)
          {
            if(record.idm==null && record.vector_id !=null)
            {
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk].platform = struct.listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
              struct.indk++;
            }
            else if(record.vector_id==null && record.idm!=null)
            {
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk].media = struct.listMedias[record.idm-1];
              struct.indk++;
            }
            else
            {
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk] = {media : null, platform : null, orderscroll: null};
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk].orderscroll = record.orderscroll;
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk].media = struct.listMedias[record.idm-1];
              struct.listScroll[struct.indk].platform = struct.listPlatforms[record.vector_id]; 
              struct.indk++;  
            }       
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        throw err;
      });

    var pr6 = db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.device;")
      .then(function (records){
        for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
        {
          struct.deviceList[i] = {value : records[i].value,  label : records[i].label};
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        throw err;
      });

    var pr7 = db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.listmsd;")
      .then(function (records){
        for(i=0; i<records.length; i++)
        {
          let aaa = records[i].namelist;
          let ccc = [];
          struct.msdList[i] = {id: records[i].idlistmsd, labelList: aaa, msds : []};  
        }

        let k = struct.msdList.length;

        db.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM safeplusdb.msd;")
          .then(function (records1)
          {
            for(j=0; j<records1.length; j++)
            {
              for(l=0;l<k;l++)
              {
                if(records1[j].listmsd==struct.msdList[l].id)
                {
                  struct.msdList[l].msds.push(records1[j].msd);
                }
              }
            }
          })
          .catch(function(err){
            throw err;
          });         
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        throw err;
      });

    Promise.all(pr1, pr2, pr3, pr4, pr5, pr6, pr7)
      .then(function(){
        console.log(struct);
      })
       .catch(function(err){
            throw err;
      });   
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

Comment: Thanks alwaysone, I will check this. It seems to be good.

Comment: Look in my edit.

Comment: Didn't actually read the question, but the whole if-else block can be reduced to something like this... struct['label${records[i].type}'] = records[i].type;

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `loadDatas` function has to be async - it is a consequence of using async calls inside it. In your current implementation you will not be able to undestand when all async calls are complete and your structure is filled with data.

You should consider chaining Promises. Take a look at this article (just ignore Angular stuff): http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/